# How to Host Service svc on Local IIS?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I am hosting site on my local IIS, The service (*.svc) file i put in MyProjectFolder/Service directory . I am getting following error. I am calling service from ajax call direct through service path.  "neo.Mysite.Net/Prent.svc"

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file
>   should be downloaded, add a MIME map

**Most likely causes:**

•The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.

•The URL contains a typographical error.

•A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

**Things you can try:**

•Create the content on the Web server.

•Review the browser URL.

•Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here

Answer (score 0):

U could refer this short and simple blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/calling-wcf-services-with-jquery-stripped-down